# Python requests + proxy + 302 redirect, why incorrect request?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, httprequest, http-status-code-302

I'm using Python requests and I send requests through a proxy. The site I'm sending requests to has 302 redirection, and the request doesn't work properly. It seems that the request sends without proxy and the site finds out my real IP.

Python code:

```
try:
    session = Session()
    request = Request('GET', url, headers=headers)
    prepped = session.prepare_request(request)
    resp = session.send(prepped, proxies=proxy, timeout=8)
    session.cookies.clear()
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.history)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("Timeout error ... :( " + "\n")
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Connection error ... :( " + "\n")
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print("HTTPError ... :( " + "\n")
```

Response history

```
<Response [302]>
```

Basically I need to send request from another IP and every time as a new user with new cookies and so on.
But with this code I can't manage to do it.
Can someone help me with this and say what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can using **requests.head** to get redirected url first.

`r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)`

Answer (score 0):

The `proxies` parameter should be a "Dictionary mapping protocol to the URL of the proxy" ([source](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request)).

[Example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}
```